# Create a SQL command that uses a subquery. New to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm required to do the below:

Write an SQL command that uses a subquery to retrieve all customer data for customers that live in a suburb other than where anyone with a last name of “Stevens” lives.

```
SELECT * FROM CustDetails
WHERE LName <> Stevens
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Here's a screenshot of the table design: [Table design](https://ibb.co/gA1PWk)

Comment: Use `!=` rather than `<>` because it looks cooler.... lol!!

Comment: Please post your table structure along with any other effort you have tried.  Your current query is almost certainly wrong, because I think you'd need at least one subquery to get the answer you want.

Comment: reading your question, i think you miss this part `live in a suburb other than`. So i think you need to add second condition: `Select * From CusDetails Where LName <> 'Steven' AND LStay = 'suburb'`

Comment: The statement you posted does not include a subquery, so no - it's not correct.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gA1PWk Here's a screenshot of the table design.

Comment: it should be `SELECT * FROM CustDetails WHERE LName <> 'Stevens' AND  (Suburb is not null OR Suburb <> '')`

Comment: Sorry Jacky, that is still incorrect.

Comment: @cddt ok, i didn't understand what OP tried to archived at first :)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: `<>` is ANSI SQL and portable. `!=` is deprecated, and shouldn't be used when writing new code.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The accepted answer wont run on both those products...) Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to identify all suburbs where a Stevens lives. Then exclude any customers which live in one of these suburbs.

```
;WITH steven_suburbs AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
 Suburb
FROM
 CustDetails
WHERE
 LName = ‘Stevens’)
SELECT
 c.*
FROM
 CustDetails AS c
  LEFT JOIN
 steven_suburbs AS s
  ON
   c.Suburb = s.Suburb
WHERE
 s.Suburb IS NULL
```